# Need output by combining DATEDIFF(hh,StartTime,EndTime) + 'Minutes' in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When running this query, I  need output by combining

```
DATEDIFF(mm, StartTime, EndTime) + 'Minutes'
```

I'm getting this error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Minutes' to data type int

I need to achieve the output like `15 Minutes`.

(15 represents the difference between StartTime and EndTime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATEDIFF function returns a INT values.
So you need to CAST it to a string.

Try something like

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(mm,StartTime, EndTime) AS NVARCHAR(2)) + 'Minutes'
```

Obviously you can use other destination string type like char\nchar etc... And use the CONVERT function instead of CAST.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCAT()`:

```
select concat(DATEDIFF(minute, StartTime, EndTime), 'Minutes')
```

`CONCAT()` will conveniently convert arguments to strings.  Also note that this spells out `minute`.  I recommend using the full name when using date functions.